# Update center Y and center X constraints in a UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints

I have created a UIVIew and add it into center X and Y;
[image]

The keyboard will overlap the View if the keyboard appear.
[image]

How do I update the constraint and make sure the view always in the center:

```
@IBOutlet weak var addViewConstraintX: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var addViewConstraintY: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var addView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var english: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var chinese: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    addView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
    print("keyboardWillShow")
}
```

Comment: `centerY = (screen.height - keyboard.height) / 2.0`, I think that is an elementary math.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different notification that you’ll want to listen for: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame

When you receive it, the notification’s userInfo dictionary will contain the keyboard’s new size.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/keyboard_notification_user_info_keys

Then just change the constant of the vertical layout constraint by half of the height of the keyboard.

Comment: To the OP, please note, if the superview actually changed, you might be fine as is. (This might be included as an explanation in your answer. The actual issue isn't detecting a keyboard... but that the underlying frame isn't changing.)

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` method

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

Elsewhere

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        addView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y - keyboardHeight/2)
    }
}
```

Comment: the "addVIew" will go to original position when I click the  "chinese" UITextField